# SSD not being recognized by ubuntu linux 14.04 and mountain lion machines

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, ssd, data-recovery

My question is as the title suggests. I have extremely important data in my samsung evo SSD that was in my macbook, and I got too overconfident while doing some repairs and didn't back it up..:(

So what happened was - I was about to remove the SSD from the mac (the screen was open) and I pressed the power button. The login screen came immediately :(. I was already in the flow of pulling it out, and I did. Now I fear the SSD might be dead, or more hopefully the partitioning table has got slightly messed up.

I bought a hard drive enclosure and put the SSD in it. I hooked the enclosure up to my ubuntu machine...and it didn't seem to recognize it. The output of sudo fdisk -l is as follows-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00059aa7

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 499711 248832 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 501758 234440703 116969473 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 501760 234440703 116969472 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 117.6 GB, 117633449984 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14301 cylinders, total 229752832 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 2139 MB, 2139095040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4177920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

As you can tell, it didn't detect it. I'm pretty sure it's format is HFS+. So I hooked it up to a mac running, Mountain Lion and it couldn't detect it in the finder, or in disk utility.

This is seriously freaking me out guys. Is there any data recovery tool you guys would recommend? Please help me. As I have some technical knowledge, I'm not scared of using a terminal or anything. And I read something about partition recovery. Can that help?

Hopefully this can get solved quick :)

Comment: Hmm, if Disk Utility isn't seeing the disk *at all*, that sounds like bad news. Have you excluded the possibility that the external enclosure is faulty, though? Many shops have these super cheap bare bones external connectors (as opposed to enclosures), maybe worth trying with one of them

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've tried with one of those external enclosures at home to no avail.

Comment: I'm not a hardware repair expert, but if you can't get the HDD to even be recognized as a device, I *think* that could mean it's a case for a recovery lab :( What I'd try as a last resort is find a desktop PC, plug the HDD directly into one of its internal SATA ports, and see whether the BIOS (and/or the OS running on it) manages to find anything. If that yields nothing either, I'd call a data recovery service like [Ontrack.](https://www.krollontrack.com)

Comment: Cross posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1204936/disk-not-being-recognized-by-ubuntu-linux-14-04-and-macos-mountain-lion

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: Apologies for crossposting. And if anyone wanted an update, I fixed the SSD on my own by using disk utility. It turned out that 3 hard drive enclosures were faulty. When I tried the fourth one, it worked like a charm :)